# Different output in SVM model and hyperparameter tuning result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, hyperparameters

I want to ask about the output of my classification model.
I have this model to do classification for my dataset. Check out my code below.

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vector, data['label'], test_size=0.33, random_state=123)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_preds = clf.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_preds))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_preds))
print('\nAccuracy Score = ',accuracy_score(y_test, y_preds))
```

I use kernel='linear' and C = 1.0. and the output of accuracy_score shows:

> Accuracy Score = 0.7777777777777778

But when i try to use hyperparameter tuning using randomized search, but i still can't get better result than the model i build before. So, i try to check using the same parameters in randomizedsearch, but i get different result. Check my code below:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vector, data['label'], test_size=0.33, random_state=123)

parameters = [  {'C': [1], 'kernel': ['linear']} ]

search = RandomizedSearchCV(n_iter = 1, estimator = svm.SVC(), param_distributions = parameters) 

search.fit(X_train,y_train) 
print(search.best_params_)
print(search.best_score_)
```

Based on my code above, the output shows:

> {'kernel': 'linear', 'C': 1}

> 0.737162980081435

Because of that, i conclude that it has same parameter, but get different result. Can someone tell me why it shows different result?

Comment: It is probably because of random seed in SVM. Try `np.random.seed(seed)` before calling the classifier?

Comment: Like this ```clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0, random_state = np.random.seed(123))``` ?

Comment: `np.random.seed(123)` then `clf = svm.SVC(...)`

Comment: `svm.SVC(..., random_state = 123)` also works.